# Add custom words in Actions for the Google Assistant

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, google-assistant-sdk

Everytime I execute google assistant and it works quite well, but there are some words which google is not having like "EDU", So when I speak it EDU and it give "ajju", "adu", "eu" and such suggestion.
So is there a way to add all such words and from next time when I speak such word it gives accurate result as I pronounced.

Comment: Are you using Dialogflow?

Comment: Yes I am using Dialogflow

Comment: You should create an entity type and use each possible word as a synonym.